How did a user cast over 100 up/down votes in a day?
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/178179 seems to say the max number of daily up/down votes is 40. Yet I saw a user with 102 up/down votes within one day. How is it possible to cast over 40 up/down votes in one day?

User with 102 up/down votes within one day (mirror 1, mirror 2, mirror 3):


They could have been cast by different accounts that were merged. Another explanation is that the user can vote on another post if a post they vote on is deleted the same day.

I did some asking around in SO chat rooms and found that it's not unusual for users, especially content curators, to regularly exceed the vote limit by multiple factors due to voting on posts that were deleted the same day.

Without disclosing whether that particular user has had an account merged ever, I think it's fine for me to say that they have not had one merged today specifically.  So it would almost certainly be from voting on deleted posts, unless there's some other way to accomplish this that I'm not aware of.

The FAQ What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes? explains the main reason why this occurs, which is that if posts one votes on are deleted the same day they cast the vote, those votes don't count toward one's daily limit. A Stack Overflow mod has also confirmed above that the other case (account mergers) hasn't occurred.

If by tomorrow they are still there then I think we have our answer…

Currently, it says 49.

@galacticninja New UTC day since this was asked.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Yes, what I mean is that it seems unusual that a user has gone over the 40-vote threshold in two separate UTC days.

@testing-for-ya I was thinking from the perspective of other SE sites, where I've yet to see users consistently exceed the 40-vote limit. It sounds like SO has an unusual volume of deleted posts.
