How to find questions and answers that are likely to be deleted within the next 24 hours?
Looking at How did a user cast over 100 up/down votes in a day? makes me wonder: how to find questions and answers that are likely to be deleted within the next 24 hours?

You mean deleted by the Roomba? If yes: only questions are deleted by the Roomba.

@rene deleted by anything. Roomba is only once a week I believe, so unlikely

You want to predict how many users will cast a delete vote on a post in the next 24 hours?

I wonder how the user on https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/402418/178179 manages to cast most of their votes on posts that get deleted within 24 hours.

@testing-for-ya I prefer public info. "All these meta questions" are a way for me to understand how SE works, which is on-topic here.

@testing-for-ya I didn't ask that.

For 10k users, go to the tools delete tab to see which questions are about to be deleted.

See my comment on your previous post where I indicated that I found out that it's not unusual for users to regularly exceed the normal vote limit in this manner, after asking SO regulars in one of their chat rooms. Perhaps asking the same people I asked would be a great way to find out.

I know of one way: visit the Charcoal HQ chatroom. Lots of potential spam is posted there, and if it's actually spam, it's usually deleted within the next 24 hours.
On some sites with lots of active reviewers, the Low quality posts review queue is a good candidate too (if you have access). Here on Meta.SE, answers which are really low quality generally don't last for 24 hours.

If you have 10K reputation you can use the tools page to find a link to new-answers-old-questions - that's the Stack Overflow link but each site has its own.
On larger sites this has lots of new answers and many of them are either questions or thank yous. In the past I've been able to flag 100 posts like that per day on Stack Overflow and they would all get deleted pretty quickly.

There is also a chat room for non 10kers, by the way.

Is there any other link/page you know where many flags are raised?
